# UICollectionView: must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I added `UICollectionView` by code.
Now, the app crash with message: `UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter`.
Do you have any idea to fix it?
`CollectionCell` is custom class of `UICollectionViewCell`.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UICollectionView* collectionView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]init];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[CollectionCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout* flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

    self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 500);
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.eventCollection];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionCell* cell = [self.eventCollection dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.item];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using self.collectionView before initializing it?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The crash is telling you pretty explicitly what is going wrong:

> UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter.

If you check [the documentation for `UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/initWithFrame:collectionViewLayout:), you'll find that the only initializer is `initWithFrame:collectionViewLayout:`. Further, in the parameters for that initializer, you'll see:

> *frame*
>
> The frame rectangle for the collection view, measured in points. The origin of the frame is relative to the superview in which you plan to add it. This frame is passed to the superclass during initialization.
>
> *layout*
>
> The layout object to use for organizing items. The collection view stores a strong reference to the specified object. **Must not be nil.**

I've **bolded** the important part. You must use `initWithFrame:collectionViewLayout:` to initialize your `UICollectionView`, and you must pass it a non-nil `UICollectionViewLayout` object.

---

One way to fix this, then, would be to simply change the order of initialization you do:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout* flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

Note that in the above example, I've assumed you want to use `self.view.frame` as the frame of `self.collectionView`. If that's not the case, insert whatever frame you want instead.

Answer (score 51):

**Swift 3.0 and Swift 4.0**

**UICollectionView**

The app crashed as soon as it launched when `UICollectionView` is initialised

*initialize like* *below* (above `viewDidLoad`)

```
let alarmCollectionView:UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init())
let layout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init()
```

*In Method* (inside `viewDidLoad`)

```
layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.vertical
alarmCollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
alarmCollectionView.delegate = self
alarmCollectionView.dataSource = self
alarmCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
self.addSubview(alarmCollectionView)
```

Worked fine after initialising like this I am using Autolayout so using `CGRect.zero` or use your own `CGRect`

**UICollectionViewController**

In case if you are using `UICollectionViewController` instead of `UICollectionView` you need to add layout when initialization

```
 let  testNavController:UINavigationController = UINavigationController.init()
 let layout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init() 
 let collectionView:UICollectionViewController = UICollectionViewController.init(collectionViewLayout:layout )              
 testNavController.pushViewController(collectionView, animated: true)
```

Comment: Inside of a collection view controller in Swift 4, you cannot use this method - will get error, "Cannot override mutable property 'collectionView' of type 'UICollectionView?' with covariant type 'UICollectionView'"

Comment: I'll check and update the answer if its not working thanks for notifying

Comment: Better to keep a collectionview inside a `UIViewController` it works fine for me

Comment: `let layout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init()
        let collectionView:UICollectionViewController = UICollectionViewController.init(collectionViewLayout:layout )
        testNavController.pushViewController(collectionView, animated: true)` Hope this one works

Answer (score 27):

Just a swift version of **Riley Avron**'s answer

```
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100)
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.delegate   = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
```

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 3.0, Swift 4.0 and Swift 5.0**

It's work for me.

```
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init())
```

In Method (inside viewDidLoad)

```
if let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
}
```

Comment: Cannot override mutable property 'collectionView' of type 'UICollectionView?' with covariant type 'UICollectionView'

Comment: This answer is **perfectly correct** but be aware you must **also** use the `. register` call to register your cells.

Answer (score 12):

## Swift 5 general solution

Can use UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout and don't forget to set your cell size

```
class YourViewController : UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize.init(width: view.frame.width, height: 250)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
    // initialized with a non-nil layout parameter
    init() {
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    }    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Swift

```
var collectionView: UICollectionView!
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
view.addSubview(collectionView)
```

Answer (score 0):

don't setCollectionViewLayout liked this:

```
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

try to set when init:

```
[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:frame collectionViewLayout:defaultLayout];
```