# CollectionView controller creation without storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, controller, collectionview

Hi all I am new to Swift and am currently stuck on the below problem.
When a row is selected on a table view controller it pushes a collection view controller but I am getting this error:

```
UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter.
```

I get the error when the row is selected on tableview controller

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'
```

Any pointer on this please?

App Delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    window?.rootViewController = CustomTabBarController()

    return true
}
```

Tab bar controller has been initialised with table view controller when the row is selected it should push to collection view controller

collection view cell has been registered in `viewDidLoad`:

```
collectionView?.registerClass(PostCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CELLID)
```

Comment: class PostCell: UICollectionViewCell {
        
        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            setup()
        }
    
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    
       func setupViews(){
       backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288927/uicollectionview-must-be-initialized-with-a-non-nil-layout-parameter

Comment: i am trying to use it without storyboard.  hence not sure how to initialise collectionview controller on app delegate

Comment: Show your cellForItemAtIndexPath

Comment: let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(CELLID, forIndexPath: indexPath) 
        
        return cell

Comment: Provide the code where you are creating collectionView

Comment: class TestCVC: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        
        collectionView?.registerClass(PostCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CELLID)
       /*****
****/
    }

Answer (score 2):

Finally resolved it. In Collection view controller initialize with below method

```
**override init(collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
    super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}**
```

And while pushing the view controller 
        **let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let newPostCollection = TestCVC(collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)**

Thank you all