# UICollectionView Initializing Problems

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to add a collection view to a container view(in uiviewcontroller, I have all my inheritance set ) and for whatever the reason  even though i initialize my collection with the Flowlayout, I am still getting an error saying :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be
>   initialized with a non-nil layout parameter' (lldb)

my code :

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: (containerTwo?.frame.height)!)
collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: (self.containerTwo?.frame)!, collectionViewLayout: layout)
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
self.containerTwo?.addSubview(collectionView)
```

Idk where else to go from here. help ?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionView: must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288927/uicollectionview-must-be-initialized-with-a-non-nil-layout-parameter)

Comment: I don't see any duplicate in my code of collection view

Comment: Are you sure you're not creating an additional uicollectionview somewhere else -- maybe storyboard?

Comment: I can post the whole code. I don't see anything. I am not using storyboard, I am programmatically coding all of my views

Comment: yeah, can you upload your code on github?

Comment: this is profileview im creating : https://github.com/addieM/_Code_/blob/master/ios

Comment: try layout.invalidate()

Comment: I have tried this out but same error.

Comment: Hi I am coding this programmatically. and why would I want to do that when im trying to add the collection inside the containerTwo View that I added to the view.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

**Note:** Untested code

You have problem registering nibFile.try this..

```
 var nibName = UINib(nibName: "nibCellName", bundle:nil)
 collectionView.registerNib(nibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: " your cell identifier")
```

this should fix your problem..for incase you may need validate your collectionView layout.I guess.

```
    layout.invalidate()
```