# Thread 1 : Signal Sigbert when trying to present another View Controller

Tags: swift

I'm currently writing an app and I need to display a chart of some kind. I created another `TableViewController` and used it's cell as Bar Chart items.

The question is:

When I try to present it from the `main Controller`, it throws the `Signal Sigbart`. Why?

Everything works just fine , for example, if I comment out the present(`ViewController`) line, and say something like `print(123)` it's all good. Anyway, here's the code that's causing the problem

[image]

BarCharController

[image]

Stack Trace

[image]

Thank you. I hoped I posted all the details!!

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: isn't it obvious in the error message? Always search for words like **resaon**, **error**, **conflict**. Here it says: **Reason: UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter**. So please show us how you have initialized your collectionView

Comment: My bad. I'm not yet used to the debugger in XCode. I was following a tutorial and he was using this as his main Controller. I apologize for the inconvenience . Could you help me with the init for this ?  I have the required one already. I'm still learning :(

Comment: use the `@` to mention users so others would be notified. But as for how to instantiate. Did you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35390967/5175709)? If that doesn't work then update your question with the code you tried...